# Pip Installing .whl files from requirements.txt Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, cmd, error-handling

I am trying to make a wheel installation from `requirements.txt`. Is there a way to `pip install` a `.whl` file. I am running Windows 10 and Python version 3.9.12.

CMD command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'TA-Lib @ file:./TA_Lib-0.4.24-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl'
```

Contents of requirement.txt:

```
stdiomask==0.0.6
strict-rfc3339==0.7
swagger-spec-validator==2.7.3
sympy==1.9
ta==0.10.1
./TA_Lib-0.4.24-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Directory Tree:

```
C:.
├───TA_Lib-0.4.24-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64
└───requirements.txt
```

Packages and versions

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
Cython     0.29.30
pip        22.1
setuptools 58.1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just refer to local file in requirement file this way:

```
./TA_Lib-0.4.24-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Based on [example](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#example)

Comment: thank you but you could have just commented this as this command does not achieve the purpose of this question.

Comment: What is the purpose of the question then? Title and content suggest that you want to install whl via `pip install -r requirments.txt`

Comment: I get this error when I do the adjustments you specified `ERROR: TA_Lib-0.4.24-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`.

Comment: Ohh now i see. Previously You had syntax error in the requirments, now you are providing bad wheel. The `cp37` in the wheel name stands for the python version (in this case `python 3.7`), you need to provide wheel for `python 3.9`, or downgrade your python version in case of missing wheel.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad thank you I will reinstall the needed version and try it again.